# How can I know if im reading a binary or a text file

Tags: c++

My program has different options: You can read a binary file or a text file, but you can the binary file option and choose a text file... How can I do to detect that you have introduced a incorrect file while  I'm doing this

```
while(fich.read((char *)&struct,sizeof(struct)))
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can I do to detect that you have introduced a incorrect file while I'm doing this

The simple answer is: You cannot.

It's impossible to distinguish plain (let's say ASCII encoded) text files from binary files.

Any of the introductory byte sequences read from the file might be valid for both.

---

The silly but common solutions for this problem are:

- give your file name an extension that implies a particular format
- let your file have a *magic byte* sequence (1-2 bytes) in the beginning and imply a particular format